# Algorithm for Computing Kronecker's Canonical Form for Matrix Pencils

Tags: matrix-analysis

Is there any ready code which gives an algorithm of expressing a matrix pencil in its Kronecker's Canonical Form?

There is an old result which gives an algorithm for an arbitrary pencil but it is lengthy and looks quite tedious.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379579900351

Comment: There is a scilab-code implementation of Van Dooren's algorithm there: http://tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/Scilab/home.html. It should be easy to convert this to octave/matlab code.

Comment: The Octave script https://github.com/TobiasZawada/kronecker.m is the Octave version of http://tn-home.de/Tobias/Soft/Scilab/home.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GUPTRI](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~guptri/) by Jim Demmel and Bo Kagstrom computes a triangular decomposition that reveals the Kronecker structure of a pencil. It is Fortran code that can be called from Matlab using a Mex-file interface.

The code is quite old, though. Probably the Fortran part can still be compiled and run without changes, but I can speak for experience that getting old MEX files to run on a modern 64-bit Matlab can require lots of tweaking.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know. Meanwhile I am almost done with mathematica code and I will post a comparison if I manage to run GUPTRI.

Comment: Could you share how you solved the problem, please? I am having the same problem, too.

Comment: @Misaki I converted your non-answer to a comment, but it's not really clear what your question is. It might be better to ask a new question, linking back to this thread, but you should consider also if this is the right site for your exact concern (which may have more to do with programming languages than mathematics).